# need to check first time opened app or not if yes go to direct main activity otherwise go to intro screen

Tags: android-layout

I need to check my app intro screen is it opened first time or it's not work properly  every time i opened my app it display it's not checking the app is first time opened or not...
sorry for my bad English need your help
This is my checking code:

```
intromanager = new Intromanager(this);
        if(!intromanager.Check()){
            intromanager.setFirst(false);
            Intent i = new Intent(IntroActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
```

class:

```
public class Intromanager {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context context;

    public Intromanager(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("first", 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setFirst(boolean isFirst){
        editor.putBoolean("check",isFirst);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean Check(){
        return pref.getBoolean("check",true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
intromanager =new Intromanager(this);
if(intromanager.Check()){
    intromanager.setFirst(false);
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}



public class Intromanager {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    Context context;

    public Intromanager(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("first", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setFirst(boolean isFirst){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("check",isFirst);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public boolean Check(){
        return pref.getBoolean("check",true);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for missing to upload my class code can u again recheck my code sir

Comment: It's work for me thank you so much sir your kindly help :)

Comment: Welcome my friend